# What are the limitations of Toad for SQL Server freeware?

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I just downloaded the freeware version of Toad for SQL Server. Toad's download site says: "the Freeware edition has certain limitations, and is not intended to be used as a TRIAL for the Commercial edition of Toad for SQL Server." It also says that no more than 5 people from my organization can use the freeware version, and that I'm not entitled to hard-copy documentation, phone assistance,  tech support or upgrades.

Is the product fully functional besides that?

Comment: Why would you want to use Toad over SSMS for SQL Server?  I believe SSMS is free and unlimited for any edition of SQL Server.

Comment: I want to use it in addition to SSMS, not over SSMS. Toad has some useful utilities, including optimizing multiple sql statements in batch mode, recommending indexes, and testing for scalability under simulated user loads. See [Toad for SQL Server Functional Matrix](http://www.quest.com/Quest_Site_Assets/PDF/Toad_for_SQL_Server_Functional_Matrix.pdf) for a full list.

Comment: I can't speak for the other features, but I know off the top of my head that starting in 2008 [SSMS recommends indexes too](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2008/12/29/SQL-Server-Management-Studio-2008-suggests-missing-indexes-with-actual.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, Nick. If the Toad freeware was fully functional, I'd probably use both. Since it isn't, I'll stick to SSMS.

Comment: Try this tool for SQL Server Physical models.

Info can be found here...

https://www.facebook.com/DataModelerTool/ or here... https://plus.google.com/108968161662966473138

Comment: @NickChammas.  For day to day work, its like Toad has a patent on the F9 key and right click context menu.  And their data display grid appearance/tabs are nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Toad site has documentation on the [limitations of Toad Data Modeler](http://modeling.inside.quest.com/entry.jspa?externalID=3304&categoryID=29) but not for Toad for SQL Server or Toad for Oracle. I found a blog post ["I love the new Toad freeware!"](http://www.toadworld.com/Blogs/tabid/67/EntryId/538/I-Love-the-New-Toad-Freeware.aspx) on their site as well claiming that the new freeware is no longer ***"crippleware"*** the way it used to be.

I've used the tool for a few days now, and there are lots of menu options disabled, so no, the product is nowhere close to fully functional.

Comment: can you describe the data export options in the freeware version.

Comment: @user56, it's been almost a year since I stopped using the trial. I don't remember what data export options were available.

Comment: Here is something that looks like a canonical link to a feature comparison matrix. http://www.toadworld.com/products/toad-data-modeler/w/wiki/10528.limitation-matrix-freeware-trial-and-commercial-versions.aspx

Comment: Here's an applicable comparison from Dell on ToadWorld: http://www.toadworld.com/products/toad-for-sql-server/w/wiki/10873.toad-for-sql-server-editions-and-feature-matrix.aspx

Answer (score 0):

No. The freeware version is limited.

However is it not too bad.

For example, data import and data export wizards are there fully. (only a templated export can not be defined (paid feature)).