# Are there alternatives to the TOAD tool for SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, tools

Are there any great tools as an alternative TOAD to be used for SQL Server?

The tool can be commerical or open source.

Comment: I agree with [pritaeas](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/18353/8972). Navicat is great, I've been using it for a while now with all sorts of databases and it has never failed me. TOAD is a great tool though, but it lacks a good look and feel and so is a little bit tricky ot learn how to use. Despite this, it's query profiling tool is great.

Comment: HeidiSQL ([heidisql.com](http://www.heidisql.com)) supports MsSQL too. Never tried it for mssql but its the best tool available for MySQL

Comment: Personally never felt like using any third party tools other than SSMS. It has been amazing all these years and is still going great. Why is that you want to use third party tools to work on MS SQL Server?

Comment: More userfriendly and increase productivity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Say TOAD for SQL Server?](http://toadforsqlserver.com/index.jspa)  I dont't have experience with it, probably you have your reason asking for a replacement tool.

Comment: Related: http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/17257/2660

Answer (score 13):

SQL Server Management Studio that comes with SQL Server?

If you need to run on non-Windows, then look at [SQuireeL](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I am a fervent user of [Navicat](http://www.navicat.com/). The Premium version allows connecting to multiple database servers. Am also very content with their support, already had several cases resolved, although sometimes it doesn't get in until the next version. (I am not affiliated with them.)

Answer (score 2):

Although the Navicat UI is more polished, the feature set and extensible nature of Apex SQLEdit blows the doors off any other QA replacement I've found.  Between replacement tokens, context sensitive custom scripts (i.e., right click a table and you're presented with a list of your own CUSTOM scripts specific to TABLES with token replacement), quick info, data mining right out of the result grid, sorting and filtering in grid, etc., etc.

At that point, you may as well keep SSMS, add RedGate SQL prompt (nice) and/or SSMS Tools (free/donate) to get only a pinch of what Apex offers.

Note, I have, in no way, explored Navicat features completely, just blown away by the apparent LACK of features during my first experience with the tool, especially where the rubber meets the road, query building and result grid features.